# MockWebServer cannot read headers

Tags: android, okhttp, auth0

I use `MockWebServer` for avoid `HTTP` request to server and make UI test. We use `Auth0` for authentication. I use `MockWebServer` as

```
this.server = new MockWebServer();
    this.server.setProtocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
    this.setUpRequests(this.server);
    this.server.start(8080);
```

And setup `0.0.0.0:8080` as domain for Auth0. MockWebServer handles requests, but when it is trying to parse header I see error: 
`Unexpected header: M�Q�5�+�����+�/����`

If I start `MockWebServer` and send request during `HTTP` clients it handles request fine. When Auth0 send request all headers are fine and don't encoded.

I've tried to use 2 approaches: custom dispatcher and add list of responses `server.enqueue(new MockResponse()...)`

```
Versions  
ok http:mockwebserver:2.7.5  
auth0:1.4.0
```

Example from external HTTP client:
MockWebServer

```
                MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
                server.setProtocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
                server.setDispatcher(new Dispatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public MockResponse dispatch(RecordedRequest recordedRequest) throws InterruptedException {
                        return new MockResponse().setBody("Hello").setResponseCode(200);
                    }
                });
                server.start(8081);
```

[image: screenshot of the message]

Comment: HTTPS vs. HTTP?

Comment: HTTP, more over I user this approach for my previous project which used HTTPS, It worked fine